# How to make sure the ordering of sending message to channel are right

Tags: go

I know this is wrong

```
func e6() {
    c1 := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    <-c1                  
    go func() {           
        c1 <- struct{}{}
    }()
}
```

and this is right

```
func e6() {
    c1 := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go func() {           //statement1
        c1 <- struct{}{}
    }()
    <-c1        //statement2
}
```

Since we cannot assume the order of the statement1 and statement2 in the right example, what if the statement2 executes ahead of statement1, and in this case, the right example just looks like the wrong example, but why is that right? Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, here is what happens after you spawned the goroutine: Either the goroutine is executed first and the channel is populated so you can read from it (`<-c1`) right away. Or the read statement is executed first, but since there is nothing to read from that channel, it waits until something can be read ("It blocks"). Now the goroutine scheduler kicks in, notices that one of two goroutine blocks and it "finally" executes the other goroutine, which populates the channel and exits, making the blocking goroutine the only remaining so it gets execution time again. But now the channel is populated, it can be read from, the value from the channel is read into nothing and the original goroutine continues, ending the function.

Please noted that this is a bit simplified, and you should definitely read up on goroutines.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
func e6() {
    c1 := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    <-c1                  
    go func() {           
        c1 <- struct{}{}
    }()
}
```

because the execution goes into a deadlock. By calling `<-c1` in the main function thread, you are blocking on a receive from an open channel. Receive will block until it receives some data from `c1` but no process is sending any data on it. The goroutine that is suppose to send on `c1` hasn't started yet since code execution got blocked before reaching the `go` statement.

In the correct implementation:

```
func e6() {
    c1 := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go func() {           //statement1
        c1 <- struct{}{}
    }()
    <-c1        //statement2
}
```

it doesn't matter which statement runs first. If `statement1` runs first, the goroutine (running in a different thread) blocks at send on `c1` (`c1 <- struct{}{}`) since `statement2` hasn't executed yet and no other process is receiving data from `c1`. This results in the entire goroutine blocking and yielding execution to the main function thread where `statement2` will execute (remember that `go` statement generally does not block). This time `statement2` will not block because some other process (`statement1`) is already ready with the data to send over `c1`. Thus both the threads continue to completion.

Similar reasoning can be made for the case in which `statement2` executes first.

Comment: In the "correct implementation", _"if `statement1` runs first, the goroutine bocks at send on `c1`"_. No, it does not since `c1` is buffered.

Comment: `c1` is buffer, but it has no any data, so if statement1 runs first, the goroutine blocks at send on c1

Comment: @PengWu If a channel is buffered and its buffer is not full, sending on it does not block but the sent item will be placed in its buffer.